# need a strategy for a tough sqlite query in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, join

I will simplify as much as possible.

```
Table A, an event table, has 4 columns: _id, timestamp, type, source_id
Table B, a source table for a type: _id, a number of other columns unique to B
Table C, a source table for a type: _id, a number of other columns unique to C
Table D, a source table for a type: _id, a number of other columns unique to D
```

I am storing up to 200 of these events (for now, may go into the 1000s), they will be of type B,C,D. When loading these events, I need to create event objects that look something like this

```
Event {
    id
    timestamp
    type
    source object (can be an object of type B,C,or D, which share a base class)
}
```

My only current strategy:

- pull all event objects
- do 3 seperate queries (Select * from B where id in  (compiled_list_of_ids_of_type_B), same for c, same for d)
- Store results from above 3 queries in 3 different HashMaps so they can be easily accessed by id
- iterate through the event objects and store the source objects in their proper events

I am not crazy about this, the querying strategy seems pretty inefficient. Any ideas on how to do this more efficiently?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce to 3 queries:

select from A where type = "type that leads to B" join on B with whatever fields you need

same for C

same for D

and while you read the results construct one complete event object for each line and insert them in whatever container you hold the final list in.
It may save a bit of memory too, considering you don't store any temporaries this way. Not much of it though.

Answer (score 0):

add an association table.

a
a2other
b
c
d

query a and a2other

a2other will tell you what table and what id.

then you can sort the a2other result and query the b c and d singularly.

Comment: thats essentially what I outlined, isn't it? I would still have to either make a query for each record or make a query for each type with a list of ids.

Comment: No because you have all the associations in one query. Then when you are doing things specific to table b you use the results and only take table b, when you do table c the same thing. I imagine if you are having the join on multiple tables you are not iterating them all at the same time, but you may want to know what they are without having to query the whole thing again. If you take the results of your main table and your associating table then you only need this once. It will be small and you can keep it.

Comment: Then when you need the table B you can ask for it, use it and rid yourself of it. And go on to table C without having to poll table a again.

Comment: I am either confused or not being clear. I am polling table A, using that to create event objects with a null source field. As I do that, compiling a list of ids per each type that will be used to query tables a,b,c. I am then closing the cursor to A, and polling each table individually with my compiled list, then filling in my event objects with those results. So I don't actually have a join at all, nor is any data polled more than once. I do however, have some memory overhead. Apologies if I am confusing your solution.

Comment: I guess I am not seeing the practical usage for this method. the reason I would use an association table is to poll the information I need, then create methods on the class I create with that data that will allow me to get the associated data for the initial query. why you would want to keep 100 or more records instantiated in memory is a little beyond my scope of reasoning. is there a potential for displaying hundreds or thousands of items ? if not then just load what is being displayed and a little more above and below to maintain a buffer. Or perhaps I am not understanding